# How to invoke a function defined inside of a component?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

### Setup

My system is KUbuntu 17.10, Qt 5.9.

I have a stackview, which actually holds many more components, but I've cut them out for the sake of brevity. Basically, when "Return the Item" button gets pressed, `submitReturnButton` signal is caught on the C++ side. Catching side doesn't have any state, it just tries to send text to set on label.

---

### Code

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickWindow>

#include "returnserver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    //boilerplate ends here

    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    QObject* returnStatusLabel = engine.findChild<QObject*>("returnStatusLabel");

    ReturnServer returner(returnStatusLabel);

    QObject::connect(window, SIGNAL(submitReturnForm(QString)), &returner, SLOT(returnPressed(QString)));
    return app.exec();
}
```

**returnserver.h**

```
#ifndef RETURNSERVER_H
#define RETURNSERVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QString>
#include <QQuickWindow>

class ReturnServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QObject* target;
public:
    ReturnServer(QObject* target, QObject* parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void returnPressed(const QString& str);
};

#endif // RETURNSERVER_H
```

**returnserver.cpp**

```
#include "returnserver.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>

ReturnServer::ReturnServer(QObject* target, QObject *parent) :
    target(target),
    QObject(parent)
{

}

void ReturnServer::returnPressed(const QString& str)
{
    //qDebug() << "the signal got to slot correctly";
    QVariant status = "Returned";

//    emit statusReady(QVariant::fromValue(status));
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(target, "setReturnStatus", Q_ARG(QVariant, status));
}
```

**QML**

**main.qml** not really relevant, just to show that the app has stackview and broken into components

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Borrowment terminal")

    signal submitReturnForm(string itemID)

    property int lineEditLength: 120
    background: Rectangle
    {
        id: mainBackground
        color: "gray"
    }

    StackView
    {
        id: stack
        initialItem: returnPageComponent
    }

    Component
    {
        id: returnPageComponent
        ReturnPage{}
    }
}
```

**ReturnPage.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Item {
    id: returnPageView

    ColumnLayout {
        id: returnPageMenu
        x: 213
        y: 99
        width: 200
        height: 282
        Layout.margins: 20

        //redundant, just to make it compile
        Rectangle {
            width: lineEditLength
            height: 40
            color: "white"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
            TextInput {
                id: itemIDEdit
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                font.pixelSize: 20
                maximumLength: 8
            }


        }

        //this label I want to set
        Label
        {
            id: returnStatusLabel
            objectName: "returnStatusLabel"
            function setReturnStatus(status) {
                console.log("set return status to " + status)
                ReturnPage.returnStatus = status
            }
            text: "empty"
            width: 100
            height: 20
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14

        }

        Button {
            id: returnItemButton
            width: 75
            height: 30
            text: "Return the Item"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
            onClicked:  submitReturnForm(itemIDEdit.text)
        }    
    }
}
```

---

### Screenshot

[image]

### Question

How can I invoke/set the `returnStatusLabel` to some text sent from C++ end, given that it is in a different component?

### What I tried

1. Make the function in `main.qml` and invoke it from C++ with root object as target.

   This did invoke the function, but the text was not set. I suspect that this is something about not using the right object, so something about lifetime.
2. Make the function in the label itself, find the object in C++ and invoke the function with the object as argument

   In this case the function did not get invoked at all, although debugger did not complain about connection not being set correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is so much code... And very little text explaining your thoughts, therefore answering is very complicated and I might miss the point completly.

> How can I invoke/set the returnStatusLabel to some text sent from C++ end, given that it is in a different component?

**You can't**. A Component is little more than a declaration, or better: a configured factory to produced a certain kind of instances. However there is no instance of such object on which you could call a function.

---

But I don't see anything *beeing in another component*. I can only see, that you make the mistake of mingeling with the QML-side from the C++-side.

To quote the documentation:

> [**Warning:**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#accessing-loaded-qml-objects-by-object-name) While it is possible to use C++ to access and manipulate QML objects deep into the object tree, we recommend that you do not take this approach outside of application testing and prototyping. One strength of QML and C++ integration is the ability to implement the QML user interface separately from the C++ logic and dataset backend, and this strategy breaks if the C++ side reaches deep into the QML components to manipulate them directly. This would make it difficult to, for example, swap a QML view component for another view, if the new component was missing a required objectName. It is better for the C++ implementation to know as little as possible about the QML user interface implementation and the composition of the QML object tree.

The correct way would be to either create the instance of the `ResponseServer` in QML so you can easily do the *wireing* here, or exposing the C++-made instance of the `ResponseServer` as context property or singleton instance to QML.
The baseline is: Do the wiring of signals in QML. Provide values as *properties* to which you can easily bind.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into this further. Sorry for providing so much code, I just didn't know what is relevant and what is not, so I created a minimal working example. Could you recommend a book or some blog about Qt Quick 2 and its interaction with C++?

Comment: I don't know much books regarding QML. The only *"book"* I have been using at the beginning was: https://qmlbook.github.io - but I think the documentation also holds a ton of information on this. Also there are many interesting questions on this side, e.g. regarding the creation of data models and so on.

Comment: thank you. It worked out better than perfectly. I registered C++ type in QML.